# Take Scheduled EBS Snapshots using Cloud Watch and Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider-gcp

I need help for scheduling ec2 volume snapshot on weekly basis and needs to archive\Delete backups older than 1 month using cloud watch rule by terraform aws.

Please guide me for write cloud watch rule using terraform.

regards,
Rams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either need to write a Lambda function in your favorite language that does this or wait for [AWS Backup Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-backup-automate-and-centrally-manage-your-backups/) to be [supported in Terraform](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7166).  Other than the new backup service, there are no native features in AWS or Terraform that can do what you want to do.

Answer (score 8):

Whilst what Tyler said was correct about snapshots until quite recently, it isn't any longer. No cloudwatch event or lambda required! AWS now has [AWS Data Lifecycle Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html) for this exact task. Terraform has been updated with a new resource here:
[https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dlm_lifecycle_policy.html](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dlm_lifecycle_policy.html)

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with an example (even the one directly from the docs) and how it works to accompany the links to the docs. I'm also not sure your module is particularly useful as it doesn't particularly simplify things while being overly restrictive. I'd maybe drop the plug to your own module for now unless it's changed to be significantly more useful.

Comment: James is right, I forgot about DLM.  This should be the accepted answer but without the plug to his own module.